# Storing multiple numbers in an array (As3)

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

```
        private var hitArray:Array = new Array [ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60];
```

Hello.

I have stored multiple numbers in an array and it appears flash does not like this, I am guessing that I am telling the array that it will either have 10 spaces, 20 spaces, etc...or the array needs to understand what variable it is datatyped to.

so my next idea was to store a hundred numbers into the array by using this

```
    private var hitArray:Array = new Array; 



    public function Main() 
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; 0 < 100; i++)
        {
            hitArray.push(i);
        }



        //iniaite health
        hitCounter = 0;
        resetPos = new Point(x, y);
        //iniation players
        _character = new player();
        timmy = new SirTimmy();
        caroline = new princess();
        goblinCanMove = true;






        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainGameLoop)

    }
```

By doing this, I would be able to achieve a greater method of hitTestPoint!

```
    private function enemyCollisionGoblin():void
    {

        //trace(aKnifeArray.length);

        //knive proccess
        for (var o:int = 0; o < aKnifeArray.length; o++)
        {
            var currentKnife:Knife= aKnifeArray[o];
            if (currentKnife.x < 0)
            {
                //trace ('backmissile gone lol');
                aKnifeArray.splice(o, 1);
                currentKnife.removeKnife();
            }


            //if (_character.x < redGoblin.x && _character.x > redGoblin.x - 600)

            for (var p:int = 0; p < hitArray.length; p++)
            {
                var number:Number = hitArray[p];


                if (currentKnife.hitTestPoint(_character.x + number, _character.y - number, true)) //|| currentKnife.hitTestPoint(_character.x - 50, _character.y - 60, true))
                {
                    trace("hit");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem I am facing is that flash does not like the for loop in the main constructor, despite it being initiated one.

It should break out of the for Loop if variable i is more than 100, but does not.

My question it, how can I store numbers in an array, so I can use that array in my hit Test Point.

Sorry, I know this is simple, but I'm currently developing and learning!

Advice will be appreciate very much!

Comment: What do you mean 'doesn't like' a loop in the constructor? You should initialize the variables in the constructor IMHO, this way you have better control of what happens where, and you consolidate the initialization logic instead of spreading it over the entire script like butter over bread. You likely have different problems than an array in the constructor, say your hittest method contains `splice()` therefore should iterate through the array in reverse order, or you'll drop an index from processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an infinite loop because your loop condition is `0 < 100` instead of `i < 100`.

```
 for (var i:int = 0; 0 < 100; i++)
```

Your first method of initializing an array is incorrect. It should instead be

```
private var hitArray:Array = new Array (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60);
```

You got the brackets wrong. You have to be careful when creating arrays using the Array constructor because:

```
var awd:Array = new Array (10);
```

The above will create an empty array with a capacity of 10.

```
var awd:Array = [10];
```

The above will create an array with a single element of the number 10. This is usually the way to create an array because it's quick and easy.

```
var awd:Array = [10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Comment: thank you to you too, I feel so silly, but have learnt through mistakes and you two :D